# Selecting a QListWidgetItem when adding it

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QListWidget` in a Form with a `QListWidgetItem` displaying "*Add new*". When I click on it, I'd like a serie of things to happen:

1. A `QInputDialog::getText` asks for the content of the new item.
2. A new item is added to the list with the given text.
3. The list is sorted, except for the "*Add new*" that stays at the end (this is done by removing the "*Add new*" item, sorting, and adding the removed item again).
4. **The new item is selected.**

That last part is the one I'm having trouble. I've tried many different approaches, all leading to the same result: the item I want selected has a dashed border and it understood as selected (by `ui->list->selectedItems()` for example), but the selection color stays on the last item before the "*Add new*".

## What I tried

- `item->setSelected(true);`
- `ui->list->setCurrentItem(item);`
- `ui->list->setCurrentRow(ui->list->row(item);`

## What I noticed

When the debugger is on with a breakpoint that slowly goes through those steps, I notice everything seems to work nicely, but the UI isn't updated before the function I'm calling is done.

Also, when I want to select a given item from the list from a slot called by another button click, it works correctly with `item->setSelected(true);` (and the others too).

My guess: I can't select the item in the same function I add it because I can't graphically select something that isn't there yet.

Any guess on how to achieve this?

## Note

If you're experiencing the same problem, please read the comment on the selected answer, it was actually a *signal* problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to select added item and after that set current row to row index of added item. This works in my example.

Example: mainwindow.cpp

```
#include <QInputDialog>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->listWidget->addItem("Add New");
    connect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *)), this, SLOT(slot_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::slot_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    if (item && (item->text() == "Add New"))
    {
        QString text = QInputDialog::getText(this, "Input item text", "Text: ");
        QListWidgetItem *newItem = new QListWidgetItem(text);

        // Add new item and sort list
        ui->listWidget->addItem(newItem);
        ui->listWidget->sortItems();

        // Move "Add New" item to list end
        item = ui->listWidget->takeItem(ui->listWidget->row(item));
        ui->listWidget->addItem(item);

        // Select new item
        // Set current row to index of new item row
        newItem->setSelected(true);
        ui->listWidget->setCurrentRow(ui->listWidget->row(newItem));
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was actually totally different: I was using the signal `currentItemChanged` instead of `itemClicked`. I accept your answer as correct because that part helped me! FYI: using `setSelected` **and** `setCurrentRow` is useless if I have the right signal.

Comment: I checked it again but if i remove setCurrentRow() and setSelected() i don't get the expected result. So, for my simple code example it's necessary. However as i don't know your source code and it works without these settings it's fine.

Comment: I guess, but what if you leave one of them? Normally, the two instructions do the same thing!

Comment: You are right it's working with just one setting of setSelected() or setCurrentRow() on my office machine running Windows 10. Initially i setup this example on a machine running Ubuntu Linux 19.04 and there i saw a different behaviour and thus synchronized current row to row of selected item. I will check this again on the machine running Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: On the machine running Ubuntu Linux behaviour is different. If i just use setSelected() and current row differs from selected item row then both are selected/highlighted. The item is highlighted darker than current row. Using just setCurrentRow() works.

Answer (score 0):

If you can select item from regular slot so just emit dummy signal from very short timer. Like this

```
//add item
//...
QTimer::singleShot(1, this, SLOT(MySlotForSelectItem())); // 1 ms timer

MainWindow::MySlotForSelectItem()
{
     //select item
}
```